# Sorting exponential numbers

Tags: sorting

I want to sort some exponential numbers like {2^2,3^3,4^2} and i want The result {2^2,4^2,3^3}.
But Mathematica Sort function apply's the powers in the result and return's {4,16,27}.
How can i get the result in the same form as input?

Comment: Something like `SortBy[Inactivate[{2^2, 3^3, 4^2}, Power], Activate]`?

Comment: @J. M.: Exactly,Thank you.

Comment: If you understand how that snippet works, please consider answering your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All credits goes to J. M.'s technical difficulties♦

The trick is to use the Inactivate function to prevent Mathematica to apply the powers.

```
Inactivate[{2^2, 3^3, 4^2}, Power]
```

Then use  SortBy function to compare the Active forms of the elements.

```
SortBy[Inactivate[{2^2, 3^3, 4^2}, Power], Activate]
```

Result:

```
{2^2,4^2,3^3}
```

Comment: Well-done! $\phantom{}$